# Eagerly loading multiple levels

Tags: c#, lambda

What could be wrong here? I have seen others include multilevel class to Lambda expression using `Select`, but I'm getting this error. Can anyone help please?

> [image: Blockquote]

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeRole = new HashSet<EmployeeRole>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeRole> EmployeeRole { get; set; }
}
public partial class EmployeeRole
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        EmployeeRole = new HashSet<EmployeeRole>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeRole> EmployeeRole { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Employee.Include(a=>a.EmployeeRole.Select(r=>r.Role)).ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: That syntax belongs to older versions of EF in EF core it is like this : `...Employee.Include(a=>a.EmployeeRole).ThenInclude(r=>r.Role)...`

Comment: What are your table/context names, (Employee and EmployeeRole) or (Employees and EmployeeRoles).

Comment: @Eldar Thank you for your help. It worked like a charm.